# RAM is being used 100% of its memory even though I'm not running anything

Tags: ram

I've been through the problem that even after logging in, after 3-4 minutes RAM memory is being used all of its memory despite I'm not using or running anything at all. For that computer freezes and doesn't respond at all. A couple of days before it was okay. I've noticed it while taking a look at the task manager's graph. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2  kernel: 4.4.0-79-generic

EDIT: Output of `free -m`:

```
    total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2999         559        1454         219         985        2010
Swap:          2859           0        2859
```

I can't run Startup Applications as before I run it, computer stops responding. And 3GB was enough for me before this problem occured

Comment: How much RAM do you have at all? Maybe it's less than Ubuntu requires?  If it appeared just like this maybe even a part of the RAM hardware died?

Comment: Please add the output of  `free -m` and `top -bo %MEM | head -n 20`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, 16.04.2 uses kernel 4.8.x. Have you manually manipulated your installed kernels? How much RAM, how much swap? Have you recently added an app to your startup applications? derHugo and RoVo have asked the right questions.

Comment: @derHugo I have 3gb RAM. It was dead enough to run anything but now smth's wrong

Comment: @heynnema I didn't manipulate anything really. I can't remember about startup applications. should I upgrade my kernel to 4.8 or 4.9?

Comment: Just make sure that all of your Software Updates are done, and open the `Startup Applications` app and see what you have starting at user login. Answer the questions asked by derHugo and Rovo (edit the results into your question, don't use the comments for that output). 3G RAM is not a whole lot, so you'd better have at least a 6G swap.

Comment: Update your answer please. People might not read comments, and you can apply better formatting.

Comment: @haynnema  The 16.04.2 release notes note that the 4.4 LTS kernel is used.  Probably no manual kernel and nothing wrong with updates.